# Customize the space between lines

Tags: line-spacing, thesis

I am working on my PhD thesis and needs to reduce the space between lines. I tried the suggested ways such as:

```
 \def\HS{\rule[-1cm]{0pt}{1.1cm}}
```

or `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`did not work. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: your question is not clear enough to answer. Do you mean reduce the space between two specific lines, or reduce the default line spacing between all lines of text or something else?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle reducing space between all the lines, table of content and so on.

Comment: You should (almost always) provide a small example document, the default linespacing is quite tight and if you reduce then things are likely to over-print or force inconsistent spacing, so if you are needing to reduce the space most likely it is because some code in your docuemnt is increasing the linespacing, so the answer is do not do that but if you show no code, no one can help. Neither of the code fragments you show have any effect on the global spacing, they just insert some space at the point that you use them.

Comment: I assume that your desire to reduce space between lines is a possible solution to an underlying problem. If we knew what that was perhaps there are other solutions. Reducing the line spacing can lead to problems like a *g* in one line overlaps with an *f* in the following line. If you really want to reduce the line spacing look at the `setspace` package, which increases line spacing, and then produce your own code for decreasing line spacing.